# How do I create a VS2012 CLR supported solution using CMAKE

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2012, cmake, clr

I have a CLR solution (VS2012) that I want to make using cmake (2.8.12). All I see to do this from the properties are:

1) add the /clr flag (under Configuration Properties -> General)
2) remove the /EHsc flag (Enable c++ exceptions)

Is there a way to do this in the CMake file itself?